# Typing HTML Attributes in Vue 3 with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

What is the proper way to type HTML attributes in Vue 3, both when dealing with `$attrs` in template and `useAttr()` in `script setup`?

In my use-case, we are specifying a name for Vee Validate's `useField` method which can either use the HTML ID, if present, or a specified prop value.

```js
<template>
    <label for="$attrs.id">{{ label }}</label> // Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'string | undefied'.
    <input type="checkbox" :id="$attrs.id" /> // Same error here
</template>
<script setup lang="ts">
import { useAttrs } from 'vue'
import { useField } from 'vee-validate'

const props = defineProps<{
    fieldName: string,
    rules: string
}>()

const attrs = useAttrs()

useField(attrs.id || props.fieldName, props.rules) // Argument of type 'unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MaybeRefOrGetter<string>'
</script>
```

#### What I've Tried

I know I could coerce to a string in the script tag or a computed, e.g. `const idAttribute = ''+attrs.id`, but that feels wrong. I also could use a ref such as `const idAttribute = ref(attrs.id as string)` but that still feels clunky.

Comment: Can't you just add `id` to props?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every key-value on $attrs is typed as `Record<string, unknown>`, so TypeScript will need your help understanding the actual type if you're using them in your code, either in the script or in the template which can be done like this:

```html
<template>
  <label :for="($attrs.id as string)">{{ label }}</label>
  <input :id="($attrs.id as string)" type="checkbox" />
</template>
```